# Visual studio does not refresh the bin folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compilation, build-process

I have Visual Studio 2010 which has a problem with one specific solution which is made of several C# projects. This problem does not come up with other projects or solution.

The problem is that if I make a change in a source file and place a break point in the code, the break point won't get hit. The warning message (when I hover the mouse over the red circle which indicates a break point) VS says that the source code file is different to whatever code which has been built and loaded.

If I remove the /obj/Debug folders then rebuild the project, everything will work fine. I placed this command in pre-Build command box (in project's properties page)

```
DEL  $(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)*.*  /q
```

It will fixe the problem if every time I run the project I re-Build it but does not really help if I just press F5 to debug the project.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of removing the /obj/Debug folders, I'd suggest cleaning your solution. Build -> Clean Solution ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5tdasz7h(v=vs.100).aspx ).

Comment: I did but it did not help. Clean command does not remove all .dll files, it just removes the temporary files built during the build process.

Comment: What kind of project is this? If the assemblies are being used by another process then they won't be cleaned or replaced when you build (hence the code being out of date).

Comment: This is an ASP.NET MVC 4 project. I run it using VS's internal web server.

Answer (score 0):

How are you referencing the other libraries in bin? Are you doing a project reference or referencing the dll ?

If you are adding the dll to the project directly make sure that you have pdb and refresh files.

If possible try adding the external projects to the same solution, and do project reference.

Comment: I have a couple of other class library project which have been referenced as "project reference". Even if I do CLEAN SOLUTION and then rebuild, I get old DLL files in the /Obj folder. I also checked and made sure that files in /obj were not read-only.